Is the difference of two points a principal divisor?
The problem comes from my thought about Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Example 6.10.1.
Let $X$ be a nonsingular complete curve and $K$ is its function field. I think any two distinct points $P,Q \in X$ satisfies $P \sim Q$, that is $P - Q = \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)$ is principal divisor. To find such $f,g \in K^*$, suppose $f$ is the generator of $P_P \subset O_P$ and $g$ is the generator of $Q_Q \subset O_Q$. Then $P - Q = \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)$.
What is my mistake?

This Is true only on $\Bbb P^1$.

@TedShifrin, I have read Example 6.10.1 and know the concept of being rational. My deduction should be contradicted to Example 6.10.1. I want to know which step is wrong.

Why can you assume that $\frac{f}{g}$ has no poles or zeroes other than at $P$ or $Q$? It's been awhile since I've thought about algebraic curves but I think this should contradict the Riemann-Roch theorem in general.

Yes, Yuan is right. $\frac{f}{g}$ generally has other poles and zeros.

To explain the mistake in the problem. I give a counterexample here, which is from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Example 6.10.2. $X$ is the nonsingular cubic curve $y^2 z = x^3 - xz^2$ in $P_k^2$. The coordinate ring is $A = k[x,y,z]/(x^3 - y^2 z - xz^2)$
For the point $P = (0,1,0)$, or written $(x,z) \subset A$. The local ring at $P$ is $A_{(P)}$. Then $P_P$ is generated by $\frac{x}{y}$, since in $A_P$,
$$
\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^3 - \frac{z}{y} - \frac{x}{y} \left(\frac{z}{y}\right)^2 = 0.
$$
But $\frac{x}{y}$ has other zeros and poles, like $(1,0,1)$, $(1,0,-1)$, etc.
